# How do I send embeds using interactions.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been trying to send an embed with interactions.py, a rewrite (to my understanding) of discord.py. However, it won't work as it does with discord.py.

Here is the faulty code:

```
@client.command(
name="embed",
description="Test",
scope=[993586870606905404],
)
async def embed(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
embed = discord.Embed(
  title="your title",
  description="your description",
  color=discord.Color.random(),
  timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/my.computer/bot.py/main.py", line 79, in embed
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
File "/Users/my.computer/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/interactions/client/context.py", line 445, in send
  payload = await super().send(content, **kwargs)
TypeError: _Context.send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'embed'
```

Please help me fix this! I can't find the answer anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

Update: I went to the discord and found the answer due to the helpful staff.

For anyone else having this issue:

This code worked for me:

```
@client.command(
name="embed",
description="Test",
scope=[993586870606905404],
)
async def embed(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
embed = discord.Embed(
  title="your title",
  description="your description",
  color=discord.Color().green,
  timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
await ctx.send(embeds=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

importing "Embed" from interactions library worked for me

code:

```
from interactions import Embed, slash_command, SlashContext

@slash_command(name="ping", description="for testing")
async def ping(ctx:SlashContext):
    embed = Embed(description="pong")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You must change the name of the embed or the name of the command and use embeds not embed for await ctx.send(embeds=...)

```
@client.command(
name="embed",
description="Test",
scope=[993586870606905404],
)
async def embed(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
embed_message = discord.Embed(
  title="your title",
  description="your description",
  color=discord.Color().green,
  timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
await ctx.send(embeds=embed_message)
```